# Best way to substitute variables in plain text using PHP

Tags: php, variables, substitution

What's the best way to take some plain text (not PHP code) which contains PHP-style variables, and then substitute in the value of the variable. This is kinda hard to describe, so here's an example.

```
// -- myFile.txt --
Mary had a little $pet.

// -- parser.php --
$pet = "lamb";
// open myFile.txt and transform it such that...
$newContents = "Mary had a little lamb.";
```

I've been considering using a regex or perhaps `eval()`, though I'm not sure which would be easiest. This script is only going to be running locally, so any worries regarding security issues and `eval()` do not apply *(i think?)*.

I'll also just add that I can get all the necessary variables into an array by using `get_defined_vars()`:

```
$allVars = get_defined_vars();
echo $pet;             // "lamb"
echo $allVars['pet'];  // "lamb"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's from a trusted source you can use (dramatic pause) [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval) (gasps of horror from the audience).

```
$text = 'this is a $test'; // single quotes to simulate getting it from a file
$test = 'banana';
$text = eval('return "' . addslashes($text) . '";');
echo $text; // this is a banana
```

Comment: Does addslashes() even out any possible syntax ambiguity?

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes. From the manual, it replaces single quotes, double quotes and NULL characters. While you don't have those, you're still inside the string. This is a beautiful, simple example of using eval; I've done stuff like this before, when I needed to hack something for one-time in-house use.UP!

Comment: Hm, and how does it react to "$name" when $name is not defined?

Comment: Same as normal php - it'll raise a notice (if you have notices on) and treat $name as an empty string.

Answer (score 11):

Regex would be easy enough. And it would not care about things that `eval()` would consider a syntax error.

Here's the pattern to find PHP style variable names.

```
\$\w+
```

I would probably take this general pattern and use a PHP array to look up each match I've found (using (`preg_replace_callback()`). That way the regex needs to be applied only once, which is faster on the long run.

```
$allVars = get_defined_vars();
$file = file_get_contents('myFile.txt');

// unsure if you have to use single or double backslashes here for PHP to understand
preg_replace_callback ('/\$(\w+)/', "find_replacements", $file);

// replace callback function
function find_replacements($match)
{
  global $allVars;
  if (array_key_exists($match[1], $allVars))
    return $allVars[$match[1]];
  else
    return $match[0];
}
```

Comment: actually, it's this (from the php manual): [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*

Comment: Yes, but is unnecessarily complicated. You are looking for white space or a word boundary.

Comment: i know it's a massive edge case and that I'm just nitpicking now, but \w won't match accented characters like çäÄ, which are valid characters.

Comment: But you spoke of PHP sytle variable names so I ruled out that possibility. :-)

Comment: oh, they're valid php variable characters. See the first code example on this page: http://au2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

Comment: So I got it right initially, or what is that supposed to mean? :-) As with all regex - know your data, use the appropriate pattern. As I don't know your data, I figured \w would be close enough. But the exact pattern was not subject of the question, was it?

Comment: how does code within find_replacements() see $allVars unless you global it?

Comment: No need to. \w+ will already go to the end of the word. Naturally a word boundary follows, so you don't have to mention it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've just come up with, but I'd still be interested to know if there's a better way. Cheers.

```
$allVars = get_defined_vars();
$file = file_get_contents('myFile.txt');

foreach ($allVars as $var => $val) {
    $file = preg_replace("@\\$" . $var . "([^a-zA-Z_0-9\x7f-\xff]|$)@", $val . "\\1", $file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be $pet? Could it be `<?= $pet ?>` instead? Because if so, just use include. This is the whole idea of php as a templating engine.

```
//myFile.txt
Mary had a little <?= $pet ?>.

//parser.php

$pet = "lamb";
ob_start();
include("myFile.txt");
$contents = ob_end_clean();

echo $contents;
```

This will echo out :

```
Mary had a little lamb.
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) might do the trick.

Example:

```
// -- myFile.txt --
Mary had a little %pet%.

// -- parser.php --
$pet = "lamb";
$fileName = myFile.txt

$currentContents = file_get_contents($fileName);

$newContents = str_replace('%pet%', $pet, $currentContents);

// $newContents == 'Mary had a little lamb.'
```

When you look at str_replace note that search and replace parameters can take arrays of values to search for and replace.

Comment: I believe so too, but the spec shows the variable is defined by a $ as the starting character, not enclosed by %'s

Comment: If you used $var instead of %var%, it wouldn't work if you had both $abc and $abcdef.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [strtr](http://www.php.net/strtr):

```
$text = file_get_contents('/path/to/myFile.txt'); // "Mary had a little $pet."
$allVars = get_defined_vars(); // array('pet' => 'lamb');
$translate = array();

foreach ($allVars as $key => $value) {
    $translate['$' . $key] = $value; // prepend '$' to vars to match text
}

// translate is now array('$pet' => 'lamb');

$text = strtr($text, $translate);

echo $text; // "Mary had a little lamb."
```

You probably want to do the prepending in get_defined_vars(), so you don't loop the variables twice. Or better yet, just make sure whatever keys you assign initially match the identifier you use in myFile.txt.

Comment: would that work if there was something like this: "$pet $petty"?

Comment: It won't work with "$pet $petty". But if you also include a postfix (like "$pet$ $petty$" or something similar) it will.

This is not how strtr works? Try it, it does.