# Using PHP variables inside MYSQL stored queries

Tags: php, mysql, variables, storage

I searched before posting this but didn't find an answer to my question.

I have a table in a database which stores queries such as (with the php variable stored in the database):

```
select * from accounts where type = 'client'
select * from accounts where user_id = $userid
select * from accounts where name = '$name'
```

I assumed that when I pulled that particular query from the database that PHP would recognized the variable and replace it but it treats it as regular text.

Is there a way to have PHP replace the $*_*_ with an actual variable that exists? I think maybe the eval() function perhaps??

Comment: from where did you execute the script? for php variable to work you should execute your sql statement within the php script

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283222/best-way-to-substitute-variables-in-plain-text-using-php

Answer (score 1):

What you might try is using it as a prepared statement. So instead, if your database stored queries looked like this:

```
select * from accounts where type = 'client'
select * from accounts where user_id = ?
select * from accounts where name = ?
```

and you use PDO prepared statements like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$statement = $pdo->prepare($secondOfTheAboveQueries);
$statement->execute(array($userId));
$account = $statement->fetch();
```

You could also use prepared queries with named variables like `user_id = :userid` instead of questions marks if you have to process a few statements at a time with various variables.

You may also want to consider stored procedures which work similarly. An explanation for both can be found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you pull the query from a database:

```
$string = ''; // Assign the real userID

while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $newQuery = str_replace('$userid', $string, $fetch['your_row_name']); 
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but this is what i would try first...

Comment: i just realized probably using sprintf might do the job as well

Answer (score 0):

sprint seems to work well. instead of storing them as $variable, I can use %s, etc.