# simple regex isn't working using preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to use `preg_replace_callback` to fill in variables in an imported document (which I control), based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283232/901048), but it's not working. As far as I can tell, the callback is never invoked, which would mean the regex is never being matched.

The bare-bones content of my `doc.html` file:

```
<p>test {$test} $test test</p>
```

The PHP:

```
$test = "ham";
$allVars = get_defined_vars();

$filename = "/path/to/doc.html";
$html = file_get_contents($filename);
$html = preg_replace_callback("/\$[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/", "find_replacements", $html);

echo($html);
exit();

// replace callback function
function find_replacements($match) {
    global $allVars;
    if (array_key_exists($match[0], $allVars))
        return $allVars[$match[0]];
    else
        return $match[0];
}
```

The output is `<p>test {$test} $test test</p>`, but I was expecting `<p>test {ham} ham test</p>`

Comment: I wouldn't use `$` as PHP already uses it for interpolation, it could lead to nasty bugs. Try using a different character, like `test {#test} #test test`

Comment: Also try putting your regex in single quotes if you use `$`.

Comment: That was it -- using single quotes around my regex. Can you write up an answer explaining why?

Comment: Nasty bug! Answer below is good, but my solution would be to just chose a different character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the dollar sign in regex is being interpolated by PHP because the regex is in double quotes.  Put single quotes around that:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('/\$[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/', "find_replacements", $html);
```

Second, the values sent to your callback include the dollar sign, whereas the dollar sign is not present in the `$allVars` array, so you must manually strip it off:

```
function find_replacements($match) {
    global $allVars;
    $match[0] = substr($match[0],1);
    if (array_key_exists($match[0], $allVars))
        return $allVars[$match[0]];
    else
        return $match[0];
}
```

Making those modifications, I was able to receive this output:

> test {ham} ham test

Comment: I spotted that second problem after I submitted the question, and fixed by using `$allVars[$match[1]]` and adding parentheses in my regex: `'/\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/'` -- Thanks for an alternate solution, though!