# How can I replace "{#text['..*var1*..'][..*var2*..]}" => {$text['..*var1*..'][..*var2*..]}

Tags: php, arrays, wildcard, str-replace

I have this text-array

```
$text = array( "T02" => array( 'EN' => 'English text for T02'), 
           "T03" => array( 'FR' => 'Texte anglais pour T03'));
$language = "FR";
$testtext = "Translated text: {#text['T03'][$language]}";
```

I need the # here because I get this text from a database through a function.

So I need to replace de # with a $

```
// This will work, but I need 'T03' and $language to be variable:

$output = str_replace("{#text['T03'][$language]}","{$text['T03'][$language]}",$testtext); 
echo $output;

// This won't work:
$output = str_replace("#text","$text",$testtext);
echo $output;   // I get ==> Translated text: {Array['T03'][FR]}
```

How can I replace "{#text['..*var1*..'][..*var2*..]}"  ==>  {$text['..*var1*..'][..*var2*..]} ?

Comment: This is PHP code, right?

Comment: I replaced the `bash` tag with `php`.

Comment: It won't work that way because you're using double quotes, so `$testtext` is not what you create the image of in your example code. See http://php.net/string and http://php.net/var_dump. If you're looking for a search and replace function with strings, take a look in the string function section: http://php.net/strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to substitute variables in plain text using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283222/best-way-to-substitute-variables-in-plain-text-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`

```
<?php
$text = "{#text['..var1..'][..var2..]}";
$pattern = '/{#(.*)/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '{\$$1', $text);
```

### @Eduard, you have no idea what you are asking for. Please use this. It's still bad but at least won't blow you app up.

```
<?php
$text = array( "T02" => array( 'EN' => 'English text for T02'), 
           "T03" => array( 'FR' => 'Texte anglais pour T03'));
$language = "'FR'";
$testtext = "Translated text: {#text['T03'][$language]}"; 
$pattern = '/{#(?P<varName>\S+)\[\'(?P<someKey>\S+)\'\]\[\'(?P<langKey>\S+)\'\]}/';

$callback = function($match)use($text){
    return $text[$match['someKey']][$match['langKey']];
};
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern,$callback, $testtext);
```

### For special request, all sanity ends here. Enter at your own risk!

```
<?php
$text = array( "T02" => array( 'EN' => 'English text for T02'), 
           "T03" => array( 'FR' => 'Texte anglais pour T03'));
$language = "'FR'";
$testtext = "Translated text: {#text['T03'][$language]}"; 
$pattern = '/{#(.*?)}/';


echo eval('return "'.preg_replace($pattern, '{\$$1}', $testtext).'";');
```

Comment: This doen't help. I get "$text['T03'][FR]}", but it doesn't activate the array.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. It's a string, why it should become array?

Comment: $text = array( "T02" => array( 'EN' => 'English text for T02'), 
           "T03" => array( 'FR' => 'Texte anglais pour T03')); is a array

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What you really want to do?

Comment: $language = "EN";
    $testtext = "Translated text: {#text['T02'][$language]}"; 
=> Should give: 'Translated text: English text for T02')

    $language = "FR";
    $testtext = "Translated text: {#text['T03'][$language]}"; 
=? Should give: 'Translated text: Texte anglais pour T03')

Comment: $output = str_replace("{#text['T03'][$language]}","{$text['T03'][$language]}",$testtext); works, but it needs to be variable

Comment: @mleko: Because of the double quoted string `$language` will be already substituted and won't work any longer (as substuted with the contenst of `$language` which is not `var_export((string) $language, true)` but just `(string) $language`. That is most likely due to a confusion by the OP about string fundamentals in PHP with double-quoted strings. Can happen, just needs education ;)

Comment: @hakre It will, my eyes are bleeding but this code works. You can check

Comment: Yes, but only with constant to string conversion warnings. Why not before assigning `$testtest` do `$language = '$language';` while keeping a backup of the original value ^^ :D - Or directly: `$language = var_export((string) $language, TRUE);`

Comment: @hakre Thats why I used `$language = "'FR'";` in my code. There is eval in code and you care about warning? May God forgive me that eval.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, may god forgive the eval. It perhaps will kill the OPs site and server one day :) Let's cross fingers it's not the last server in the world then :)

Comment: @hakre if he will just copy paste that blasphemy I wrote I'm quite sure his server will be killed. I doubt it will be God, I bet on some bored 11 year old.

Comment: @mleko: Just a hint: Better not answer. Esp. as OP begged for code in comments. Just kill it, you find better questions to deal with I'm sure.

Comment: @mleko: Thank you! It's working now for my purpose. I don't see why this code is blasphemy?

Comment: this become way to long. Lets move to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55201/questions-24065389

Comment: I understand. I don't have 20 reputation, so I can't answer you in the chatroom. Thanks anyway.